# WIFI Speed / Connectivity issues : Xfinity / SB 6190 / Google Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

For the past few weeks, I have been facing issues with internet dropping randomly,
Slow, inconsistent speeds etc. This is affecting work related video calls.
My apologies if I have not used appropriate technical terms as I am not super familiar
with networking terminology.

Below are the details of the set up :
Internet Plan : Xfinity 400(download) / 10(upload)
Modem : Arris SB 6190
Router : Google - Wifi - Mesh Router (AC1200)

The modem feeds the router. The router then feeds a TP Link TL-GS108 network switch
So I have Wifi and wired ethernet(in a few rooms)

The main Hub is in the basement(where the internet cable comes in) and another Hub is
on the 2nd floor. Have tested the Mesh multiple times, Google Home app says "Good Connection"

I have moved from a 100 MBPS plan to a 400 MBps plan with no relief. Both Wifi and wired
connnections have performance issues. Internet drops(both Wifi and Wired) completely or is very slow

Not sure if it is related, but the issues appear to have begun after migration to the Google Home App

I have done a factory reset, disabled UPnP, restarted router multiple times but to no avail.

The Wifi/Wired speeds vary wildly throughout the day.

Called Xfinity, they tried to do some troubleshooting, reset the modem etc but conveyed that they cant do much more
than pinging my modem as it is not their equipment

The speed on the wireless network is always a lot lower than what a direct wired connection to the modem shows.

Below is a link to the connection state, event log of the cable modem from the admin page :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1quBgaooz_ArtateP5lZ9YW8DjuVhNLUWjXiwg_Ldqtc/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions / tweaks to overcome issues appreciated

Comment: Connect just one computer (device) to the router on the ISP network. Disconnect everything else. Check the speed. If still slow, call the ISP.  The main router may need to be replaced with a better router.

Comment: I am guessing the Google Home WiFi mesh devices are connected to the `TP-Link TL-GS108`? The switch is auto negotiating each port, on the ports connected to the Google Home WiFi devices, what speed is being negotiated?